# Is it possible to unit test this method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to get my head around unit testing and mocking. So as I have it, unit tests, test a single method with provided parameters expecting a specified outcome using `Assert`. Now almost all my methods that I implement communicate with the database in one way or another. And most of them have multiple responses depending on what happened within the method. Exceptions might be thrown as well but they are caught by the catch clause and handled gracefully.

I have been trying to write a unit test for the following method but I don't think I am getting the mocking right on it. Here is the method in question:

```
    public override async Task<RegistrationResponse> RegisterEndpoint(RegistrationRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            //Check that IP address is valid, returned malformed if not a valid IP
            var isValidIp = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(request.IpAddress, out _);
            if (!isValidIp)
                return new RegistrationResponse { Result = RegistrationResponse.Types.Result.Malformed };

            //Check that the record doesn't exist in the DB already
            var doesExist = _context.Services.Any(x => x.IpAddress == request.IpAddress && x.Type == request.Type);
            if (doesExist)
                return new RegistrationResponse { Result = RegistrationResponse.Types.Result.Duplicate };

            //Add the service to the database
            _context.Services.Add(new ServiceModel
            {
                IpAddress = request.IpAddress,
                Type = request.Type,
                LastAccessed = DateTime.Now
            });

            //Save the service to the database
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception 
            await _logClient.LogException(ex, new object[]{ request });
            //Return failure result
            return new RegistrationResponse { Result = RegistrationResponse.Types.Result.Failure };
        }

        //Return successful result
        return new RegistrationResponse { Result = RegistrationResponse.Types.Result.Success };
    }
```

Would greatly appreciate if someone can maybe explain to me how to write a unit test for something like this; because the majority of the articles on the internet just use a basic calculator as an example and that doesn't help at all when it comes to *"complex"* method like this.

Comment: One approach is to make your context implement an interface that you can easily mock.

Comment: @DavidG - so instead of it just being a DbContext, create an interface that inherits from DbContext and use that as my context instead using DI?

Comment: Well, interfaces can't inherit from classes, so more the other way round..

Comment: Of course, okay I'll give that a try and see where I get!

Comment: this is not a method you would unit test. read what unit tests are. what you need is integration tests for it

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself, is what do you want to test? This method, as clearly shown by the comments, actually performs a series of distinct tasks: input validation, business rule validation, storage and response. Each of these steps are very short, and that's why it's tempting to leave it all together. But that's part of why you find it hard to unit test. I'd advice to split each step up into a separate method or even delegate to a separate layer, and then test each of these separately.